# Study design for evaluation of timing-precision tradeoff

Tags: experiment-design

I am proposing to recruit 15 subjects for a study examining efficiency of a particular task (dependent variable), which may vary considerably between subjects. I am hypothesizing that people who score better on two assessment measures (timed scores) will perform less efficiently of the task of interest.

Due to the small number of subjects, and high variability between subjects...what is the best study design and method of analysis?

Comment: In what sense is this w/i subjects / repeated-measures? It sounds like you have a regular, old multiple regression with 2 continuous explanatory variables & 1 continuous response variable. Also, can you clarify the nature of the variables? Does prior theory specify a specific relationship between the 2 EVs?

Comment: EVs would be related, but are two different tests. one requires basic motor skill while the other simulates daily tasks. There is also another assessment I am proposing, which is not related to the previous two. Subjects move upon request and are assigned errors based on performance. Errors are categorized and I hypothesize specific errors to be associated with DV.

Comment: Unless you provide more details on the measures, I agree with @gung, except it sounds like from your comment that the DV is categorical, in which case you could use a multinomial logit model. 15 subjects will generally not be enough to get anything useful out of a logit model. What are you really expecting to generalize to with only 15 cases? Also, you seem to be asking about experimental design as well. That's a related, but separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Observational and cross-sectional study designs only apply to cases where data are collected from existing resources, like school records, hospital forms, or other. You are proposing a experimental study. Therefore it is correct to call these people "subjects" because you are actually subjecting them to something. In cross sectional studies, it is never appropriate to refer to people in such a way.

If you intend to manipulate some form of experimental condition, then you should consider randomizing participants to do one task or the other. You might also repeat a certain task a certain number of times, leading to a repeated measures study design. Nonetheless, these considerations only serve to increase the power of the study design: your hypothesis only concerns the timing-precision tradeoff which can be measured objectively.

Why can't you recruit more people? Is this an incredibly tedious and lengthy task to perform, or for you to evaluate?